# Two javascripts not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have website and want to add some script in it. when I try to add cant because two javascripts not working together:

my html code

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://2gdmedia.com/css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://2gdmedia.com/css/component.css" />
        <script src="http://2gdmedia.com/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://en.2gdmedia.com/reveal.css">    

        <!-- Attach necessary scripts -->
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://en.2gdmedia.com/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  // trigger reveal manually.
  $('#myModal').reveal({
     animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
     animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
     closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
     dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
  });
});</script>
    </head>
```

only when I remove this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
```

then works first javascript :) please help me and not give this question down rate because I've recently been banned. Thank you in advance. If any details needs provide Im ready to comment :)

Comment: That title is hilarious

Comment: off topic "please debug my code question" - if you want to receive help update your code with specific errors and issues you have and attempts you've tried

Comment: Try putting hte jQuery link above all other links to any javascripts. Modernizr included.

Comment: Maybe you've been banned for a reason... Try to focus on the problem. Ask yourself - why would a script not work. How does it not work exactly - does it show an error in the console. What is that error? Does Google know about the issue? What I am saying is, try to minimize the problem to something that you cannot solve trivially and then ask only for this. What you ask now is for a free solution without showing any effort yourself, which is definitely not welcome in SO. If you improve the way you ask, you will get valid responses, rather than bans. Give it a try, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @yuvi in combination with the OP's profile pic, it does make for a pretty good laugh.

Comment: Recently been banned?  You should take that up with admin, not us.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester [I made a drawing to illustrate it too](http://oi61.tinypic.com/ru9ta8.jpg)

Comment: I tried it out and it did work. When I comment out the jquery library, two error messages did occuur in the error console. I think there is somewhere a mistake in configuration in the reval method (I didn't change the order of the script includes). I tested it with FF 3.28, FF24.0, FF 30.0, IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be because of jquery conflict.if this is the case use noConflict of jquery.or add the compatible version of jquery to you page.

if not this then first add jquery then all other file and see.